# ListView update via BLOC pattern issue

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am learning the Bloc patter and in general my code is working. But my problem is that the BLOC builder doesn't seem to rebuild the ListView properly, as every time it is updated from the BLOC with respect to the ListView data, the position of the scrolled list is lost and thus the list ends up at the top position.

As far as I know the aspects which widgets need to be rebuilt and which not are managed by BLOC and Flutter. This also incudes the scrolling position that should be retained. Or am I wrong here?

```
 class SubPageTasksOverview extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubPageTasksOverview({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeData = Theme.of(context);

    return BlocListener<TaskBloc, TaskState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is MyTaskInitializedState) {
          BlocProvider.of<TaskBloc>(context).add(MyTaskStartObservationEvent());
        }
      },
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          const Divider(
            thickness: 3,
            indent: 0,
            endIndent: 0,
            height: 20,
          ),
          ListTileElementAddNewTask(),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child:
                  BlocBuilder<TaskBloc, TaskState>(builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is MyTaskReceivedState) {
                  //define the order by priority
                  state.tasks
                      .sort(((a, b) => a.priority.compareTo(b.priority)));
                  return ReorderableListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: state.tasks.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                        return ListTileElement(
                            key: Key(state.tasks[index].id.toString()),
                            myTask: state.tasks[index]);
                      },
                      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                        if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
                          newIndex = newIndex - 1;
                        }

                        //Add the project on the new Position

                        var projectToMove = state.tasks.removeAt(oldIndex);
                        state.tasks.insert(newIndex, projectToMove);

                        var index = 0;
                        state.tasks.forEach((element) {
                          element.priority = index++;
                        });

                        BlocProvider.of<TaskBloc>(context)
                            .add(MyTaskCreateEvent(myTaskList: state.tasks));
                      });
                } else {
                  return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [CircularProgressIndicator()]);
                }
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You may need a `ScrollController ` for your `ListView`

Comment: Yes, I thought about ScrollController too, but it doesn't seem to be a "clean" solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.

Since the BLOC emits other states like "Loading" (after each event) the CircularProgressIndicator() widget is build for a very short period:

```
else {return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [CircularProgressIndicator()]);}
```

After the loading was successful the updated state "MyTaskReceivedState" was triggered (with new updated data).

Solution is: only to build the ListView when new data for the ListView arrive and to avoid using the CircularProgressIndicator() or other States and Widgets in this combination.

```
buildWhen: (previous, current) {
                return current is MyTaskReceivedState;
```

Comment: You save my day! My case has materials in state so I have to check:
`buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous.materials != current.materials,`